# merging multiple CSV files in one with same header but different csv files name with python

Tags: python, csv

I'm new in python ...I have tried to apply this code to merge multiple csv files but it doesn't work..basically, I have a files which contains stock prices with header: date,open,High,low,Close,Adj Close Volume... . but each csv file has a different name: Apl.csv,VIX.csv,FCHI.csv etc..
I would like to merge all these csv files in One.. but I would like to add a new columns which will disclose the name of the csv files example:

stock_id,date,open,High,low,Close,Adj Close Volume  with stock_id = apl,Vix etc..
I used this code but I got stuck in line 4
here is the code:

```
  files = os.listdir() 
  file_list = list() 
  for file in os.listdir():
      if file.endswith(".csv")
      df=pd.read_csv(file,sep=";")
      df['filename'] = file
      file_list.append(df) 
  all_days = pd.concat(file_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True) 
  all_days.to_csv("all.csv")
```

Someone could help me to sort out this ?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the indentation level matters, and you need a colon at the end of an if statement. I can't speak to the method you're trying, but you can clean up the synax with this:

```
files = os.listdir() 
file_list = list() 
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        df=pd.read_csv(file,sep=";")
        df['filename'] = file
        file_list.append(df) 
all_days = pd.concat(file_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True) 
all_days.to_csv("all.csv")
```

Comment: Hi Thank you sjc..but I don't think the error is coming from indentation..I got an error on this line if file.endswith(".csv"):, I'm not sure that the method is suitable for what I would klike to do

Comment: My main issue is this: how to  create a columns in the single files and put the name of each csv files, date time series as well

Comment: Right, in the code you posted you were missing the colon at the end of the if statement. It's there in the snippet I posted.

Comment: Hi sjc , I used your code but still got an error...apparently the code is not able to pick up each csv files name and store it in column..any ideas please?

Comment: Hi sjc is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.

Comment: Hi Sjc thank you is work  but the  name  is located in the right side is there is a way to put in the left side? i

Comment: I have  this  type of  name  "0P00015XEO.F.csv" is there  is  the way to only have this "0P00015XEO.F" instead of " 0P00015XEO.F.csv" ?

Comment: You can use `all_days[["column_1","column_2",etc]].to_csv("all.csv")`, where you put in the names of your df columns, to select the order of the output columns. I don't understand your other extra question, do you want to rename files in your directory or just parse strings to remove a period?

Comment: Hi sjc.. thank you for your reply, I would like to use the name of the csv file only.. at the moment I have 0P00015XEO.F.csv" it would be great to have the that name in the column it without .csv

Comment: You can trim the last 4 characters off of the end of the file string (so, the ".csv") with `df['filename'] = file[:-4]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new in python ..here is what I'd like to do..I got a folder with multiples csv files ( 2018.csv,2017.csv,2016.csv etc..)500 csv files to be precise.. each csv contains header "date","Code","Cur",Price etc..I'd like to  concatenate all 500 csv files in one datafame...here is my code for one  csv files but it's very slow , I want to do it for all 500 files and concantanate in one dataframe :

```
 DB_2017 = pd.read_csv("C:/folder/2018.dat",sep=",", header =None).iloc[: 0,4,5,6]

 DB_2017.columns =["date","Code","Cur",Price]

 DB_2017['Code'] =DB_2017['Code'].map(lambdax:x.lstrip('@').rstrip('@'))

 DB_2017['Cur'] =DB_2017['Cur'].map(lambdax:x.lstrip('@').rstrip('@'))

 DB_2017['date'] =DB_2017['date'].apply(lambdax:pd.timestamp(str(x)[:10)

 DB_2017['Price'] =pd.to_numeric(DB_2017.Price.replace(',',';')
```